# High availability in JBoss Fuse Fabric for CXF Rest services

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse, fabric8

We are trying to figure out how best to create a highly available Fuse Fabric infrastructure where there should not be any requirement for client side configuration. We mostly have CXF Rest services. If we create odd number of fabric containers and join them, will it create a highly available Fabric WITHOUT any client side configuration? Meaning, can the client point to one URL and Fuse Fabric will be able to fail over to any other container of the Fabric if one of them is down? I have read through multiple documents but could not find any direct answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http-gateway http://fabric8.io/gitbook/gateway.html to expose single ip:port for a service that is highly available in fabric

Comment: Thanks, Bilgin. As I understand, this gateway would need to be installed in a Fuse server that should typically run in the same box as that of the client application and this Fuse server also should be part of the same Fuse Fabric. Is that correct?

Comment: The gateway component works perfectly fine for JBoss Fuse 6.2. There was a bug in this component for 6.1. As per my tests, the gateway component should run ina  container that is in the same Fabric hosting the services. That way the gateway componen t can look up the Fabric registry and do the load balacing across mutliple server endpoints.